# Laravel 5 string as primary key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working on a project that uses Laravel 5.5 and one of the models has its ID defined by the user. Below the model, setting `$incrementing` to false and having it in the `$fillable` array.

```
class AIOpportunity extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ai_opportunity';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_opportunity';
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_opportunity',
        'budget',
        'created_by'
    ];
}
```

The problem: when trying to execute this query :

```
$rec = AIOpportunity::where('id_opportunity', 'abc')->first();
```

It executed the following query in the database:

```
select * from ai_opportunity where id_opportunity=abc
```

Which throws an error because of the type. Is there something else I can do so Eloquent understands it's a `varchar` field?

Comment: what's your error exactly?

Comment: it says that the table doesn't exist. It does, it's just the error message the MySQL throws when you try to run this query

Comment: Then the table doesn't exist. It's not a varchar or not. Actually `varchar` accepts all fields. Run `php artisan optimize` and if that doesn't fix your issue check your table name

Comment: can you share the ai_opportunity table migration, please?

Comment: add `protected $keyType = 'string';`

Comment: @Razor It didn't work. I just googled it and saw this is in the documentation. I suspect there is something wrong in another place that is not this model.according to the docs this should work.

Comment: Is there a reason you've made the primary key this string rather than just adding a unique column?

Comment: Same as @Rwd. This approach doesn't look pretty solid to me. How do you avoid duplicates? Why don't you use another column to store this user id?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was not a Laravel problem, the settings in my question are OK. The problem was in the database I had locally. Although the table existed and it looked all right when I accessed via PhPMyAdmin I could see it there but also there were error messages saying that the table didn't exist.

Yes, pretty weird. I just deleted the local database and restored a backup from production. it works. The problem was in the database itself, not the Laravel App.